# Effect of protein hydrophobicity on metal interaction

Tags: ph, coordination-compounds, proteins

I'm studying how metals and proteins interact (metal-protein complexes). I've found that almost all proteins could bind with metal at higher $\mathrm{pH}$ values, but also found some proteins showed lower intensity in metal-protein complexes.

I understand $\mathrm{pH}$ has an effect on the charge state of amino acid side chains of proteins, but I really had less information about the effect of $\mathrm{pH}$ on protein hydrophobicity, and hydrophobicity's effect on the protein's ability to bind metals.

Comment: Thats a very interesting topic : ) What analytical technique do you use? The pH value will inevitable influence the hydrophobic properties of the protein as amino acid side chains get protonated/deprotonated. If I remember it correctly, at least the log P values are most often specified for different pH values. That would be one way to systematically study the effect of pH on the hydrophobicity of individual amino acids.

Comment: So does this question have to do with pH value or hydrophobicity?